Quotient of $\mathbb R^2$ that is not Hausdorff
Problem: Give an example of an equivalence relation $\sim$ in $\mathbb R^2$, whose equivalence classes are closed sets, but the quotient space $\mathbb R^2/\sim$ is not Hausdorff.
So far: My thinking was to declare $(x,y)\sim (x',y')$ iff $(x,y)=(x',y')$ or $y=y'=0$, so we collapse the $x$-axis into a point and leave others untouched in the quotient space. Then the preimages of these classes are closed in $\mathbb R^2$, so the classes form closed sets in $\mathbb R^2/\sim$, as desired. I thought we would run into issues when taking neighborhoods of the ''$x$-axis'' in the quotient space, but now I'm not so sure if this space is Hausdorff or not.
Alternatively, I considered $(x,y)\sim (x',y')$ iff there exists some $\lambda>0$ s.t. $x=\lambda x'$ and $y=\lambda y'$. Here the Hausdorffness would collapse when taking a neighborhood of $[(0,0)]$?

But then the preimage of the class of rational pairs $[q]$ is $\mathbb Q^2$, which is not closed in $\mathbb R^2$, which in turn means $[q]$ is not closed? Or am I missing something?

Oh, sorry, missed wanting equivalence classes to be closed.

In the second, I'd think the equivalence class of $(1,0)$ would be the (strictly) positive $x$-axis which isn't closed?

Hint: Use a group of more general diagonal matrices.

How about something like: the equivalence classes are ${ (x, y), (x, -y) }$ except that $(0, 1)$ and $(0, -1)$ are put into separate equivalence classes?  So roughly, the quotient looks like the closed upper half plane except with $(0, 1)$ doubled.

The space you refer to is indeed Hausdorff, since any point not on the x-axis has a neighborhood disjoint from a neighborhood of the x-axis. It is homeomorphic to the union of two 2-discs glued together at a point on their boundaries, with the rest of the boundaries removed.

@MartianInvader I'd think the quotient space in the first case would not be first countable, since for each continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$ you would have the neighborhood ${ (x, y) \mid y < |f(x)|}$ of the $x$-axis.  So, given any countable collection of neighborhoods of the $x$-axis, for each $n$ choose $\varepsilon_n$ such that $B_{\varepsilon_n}((n, 0))$ is contained in the $n$th neighborhood, then construct an $f$ where $f(n) < \varepsilon_n$ for each $n$.

You could build something similar to the line with two origins ( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold). Define the relation $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ if  $a=c$ and either $a\neq 0$ or $b=d$. The equivalence classes are either the points $(0,b)$ or of the form $\{(a,b):b\in \mathbb{R}\}$ where $a\neq 0$. We have that the space is not Hausdorff since for any two distinct reals $x$ and $y$ we have that $(0,x)$ and $(0,y)$ cannot be separated by disjoint neighborhoods.
